# Como ingresar por teclado atributos de un objeto que aún no he creado?

Tags: java, poo, objeto, atributos, data-atributos

Me piden que diseñe un programa en el que tengo que ingresar los parámetros de un objeto a traves de los setter. He creado una clase aparte con los atributos (private) y los métodos. En la clase Principal tengo que introducir los parámetros de los opor teclado. Mi problema es que no puedo usar los setter si aún no tengo instancia, y a través de la clase Scanner no puedo crear una instancia.
Acompaño una parte del programa que llevo escrito:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        boolean salir =false;//declaro la variable que nos permitirá salir del programa
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(!salir){//cuando !salir=false => saldremos del bucle
            
            System.out.println("Introduzca el número correspondiente a la acción que desea hacer:\n 1. Nuevo Empleado.\n 2. Ver DNI Empleado.\n 3. Ver Sueldo.\n 4. Salir.\n");  
                        
            int opcion = teclado.nextInt(); 
            
            switch (opcion) {

            case 1:
//necesito esta linea y no sé donde colocarla:                       
                    Empleado empleado_1 = new Empleado(); 
                    
                    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del empleado: ");
                    String nombre = teclado.next();
                    empleado_1.setNombre(nombre);
                    
                    System.out.println("Introduzca DNI del empleado: ");
                    String DNI = teclado.next();
                    empleado_1.setNumDNI(DNI);
```

Comment: Pues como ya estás haciendo en tu código, con otras variables como por ejemplo DNI.

Comment: Pero el DNI es un String y lo puedo meter a través de Scanner (con next, o nextLine), pero a través de Scanner no sé como meter un objeto de la clase Empleado, que uso en lugar de nextLine?

Comment: No tengo muy clara la duda. Puedes crear una instancia e ir usando los setters por orden, según te vengan los datos desde consola. O puedes ir recolectando los datos desde consola y, cuando los tengas todos, crear la instancia e inicializarla. Es decir, de Scanner solo sacaras Strings o int, pero luego tienes que hacer las llamadas a los métodos setters adecuados (y hacer conversión de datos si toca).

Comment: Realmente Scanner no tiene algún método que te ayude a insertar objetos, la manera en la que insertas los datos según lo muestras en tu código es la correcta (dato por dato). Hay una manera de realizar lo que pides pero dado tu grado de programación no creo que sea la solución que busca tu problema. Tal vez no estas abordando bien tu duda, por favor se mas claro.

Comment: @IsaacPerez la solución que comentas se encuentra en la respuesta que di?
De no ser así, podrías indicárnosla?

Comment: Creo que si porque en el return estas creando una instancia. Pero aún me falta completar más código antes de poder probarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te has dado cuenta, no es posible leer un objeto de una clase de usuario (las clases que creas tú, ej: tu clase "Empleado") en el Scanner estándar de Java.
Las opciones que te quedan son:

1. Crear un método público y estático en tu clase Empleado, el cual cree el Empleado según la entrada del usuario. Además de esto, crearía un constructor para facilitar la creación del Empleado. Y por último llamaría al método Empleado.leer() desde el "case 1:" de tu switch.
   Ej:

```
//constructor
public Empleado(string nombre, string DNI) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.DNI = DNI;
}

public static Empleado leer() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del empleado: ");
    String nombre = teclado.next();

    System.out.println("Introduzca DNI del empleado: ");
    String DNI = teclado.next();

    return new Empleado(nombre, DNI);
}
```

2. Dejar el código tal cual está, ya que en el código del "case 1:" de tu switch ya estás logrando el objetivo (con la limitación de tener que crear la instancia de Empleado primero, antes de ejecutar sus setters). O sino también se puede usar parte de la opción 1), creando el constructor del Empleado y llamándolo al final del bloque "case 1:".
   Eso sí, si en tu tarea te pidieron usar los setters, no te queda otra que crear una instancia del Empleado primero. SALVO que uses los setters dentro del constructor (en vez de las asignaciones que yo escribí). De esa forma estarías cumpliendo con ese requerimiento y también obtendrías tu objetivo de poder crear el Empleado al final.
3. Crear tu propio Scanner (ya sea mediante herencia del Scanner que provee Java o haciéndolo desde cero).